# Qual é a implementação no ionic 2 para evitar a repetição de código?

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Eu tenho uma "tab" e gostaria de coloca-la no header, porém eu gostaria que esta "tab" e seus elementos fossem o mesmo para todas as telas, assim como também alguns design de .scss. Qual é a melhor maneira para fazer este tipo de implementação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso criando componentes no Ionic2.

Exemplo 1:
https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-custom-loading-component-in-ionic-2/

Exemplo 2:
Fiz um componente de barra de progresso. Para fazer ele tive que criar um novo componente:

`ionic g component progress-bar`

Editar os arquivos conforme minha necessidade:

`components/progress-bar/progress-bar.ts`

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'progress-bar',
    templateUrl: 'progress-bar.html'
})
export class ProgressBarComponent {
    @Input('progress')
    progress: number;

    constructor() { }

}
```

`components/progress-bar/progress-bar.html`

```
<div class="progress-outer">
    <div class="progress-inner" [style.width]="progress + '%'">
        {{progress}}%
    </div>
</div>
```

`components/progress-bar/progress-bar.scss`

```
progress-bar {
    .progress-outer {
        width: 96%;
        margin: 10px 2%;
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .progress-inner {
        min-width: 15%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background-color: #COR PRIMARIA DO SEU APP
    }
}
```

Em seguida declarar ele globalmente:

`app/app.module.ts`

```
import { ProgressBarComponent } from '../components/progress-bar/progress-bar'

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
...
        ProgressBarComponent
    ],
...
    entryComponents: [
...
        ProgressBarComponent
    ],
...
})
```

Agora é só usar onde gostaria de aplicar:

`pages/exemplo/exemplo.html`

```
...
<ion-content padding>
    <progress-bar [progress]="progressoUpload" *ngIf="iniciadoUpload"></progress-bar>
...
```

Para receber e enviar parametros entre os componentes existem dois decorators importantes @Input e @Output. Infelizmente não vou conseguir LINKAR a documentação para o uso deles. Mas no meu exemplo tem o @Input